# Spring Beans creation and accessing methods

Tags: spring, spring-ioc

```
@Service
public class SampleClass implements SampleInterface{

    @Transactional
    public void methodA(){
        SampleClass bean = ApplicationContext.getBean(SampleClass.class);
        bean.methodB();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void methodB(){
    //statements.
    }
}
```

is there any problem calling methodB() like that in the same class? I see lot of code like that. I don’t feel it is the right way. But I don’t know what are the consequences. Could anyone please let me know?

Comment: It makes no sense at all. Why not call `methodB` directly? `@Service` beans are supposed to be singletons, thus this will have the same effect. The only thing you've here is an unecessary degree of complexity and IoC principle violation.

Comment: It's probably used to start a new transaction, where the method B would use REQUIRES_NEW. If that's the case, it would be much cleaner to put methodB in another bean, injected in SampleClass.

Comment: @JBNizet Inorder to start a new transaction when methodB is invoked, we can specify @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)

Comment: it makes sense when you want to go through the proxy object of Sample class rather than directly calling the method . Transaction handling in spring is implemented using proxy objects, I guess may be because of that your code has such style of method calls